# how can send my text to the right with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to send my text to the right as the images below , but however when I want to send it. it doesnt work can I fix it? my html looks like this . if someone can help me with this i will appreciate

Here is HTML structure and CSS:

```css
div#mapdiv2 {
  width: 512px;
}

div#map {
  width: 512px;
}

div#panodiv {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

div#panodiv2 {
  width: 512px;
}

div#mapdiv2 h2,
div#map h2,
div#panodiv2 h2,
div#pano h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

div#mapdiv2 p,
div#map p,
div#panodiv2 p,
div#pano p {
  font-size: 11px;
}

div#pano {
  width: 512px;
}

div#mapdiv2 img,
div#map img,
div#panodiv2 img,
div#pano img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_feactures">
  <h1>Feacture</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Aenean massa Aenean commodo <span>ligula eget dolor Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor ligula eget dolor Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor</span></p>
  <div class="wrap_feactures">
    <div class="wrap_feactures_content">
      <div id="mapdiv">
        <div id="mapdiv2">
          <img src="img/check.png">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing<span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
          <img src="img/check.png">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing<span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="panodiv">
        <div id="panodiv2">
          <img src="img/check.png">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing<span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="pano">
          <img src="img/check.png">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing<span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what i try to achieve

[image: my_html]
[image: psd]

Comment: what do you mean by "send text to the right" , your codes shows a single column when runing and images show a few columns

Answer (score 0):

Your h2 and p are by default display: block, which means it will take 100% width of their parent.

Easiest solution is to wrap h2 and p in div with a class, and asign flex to their parents:

```
<div id="pano">
    <img src="img/check.png">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing<span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then CSS:

```
#pano {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: left;
}

#pano img {
    width: 100px; //Or what ever you want
}

#pano .wrapper {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Repeat with other divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:inline-block;` ti the `<img>` CSS and also try something like this:

```
<div id="mapdiv2">
                <img src="img/check.png">
                <div class="special">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing<span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
                </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.special{
  width: 80%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Play around with the widths and margins until you get the result you want

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to rap the text in a `div` or give both a class

```
<div id="map">
    <img src="img/check.png">
    <div class="text" 
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing<span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div#map img {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
}
div#map .text {
    width: 90%; /*or any width*/
    float: rigth;
}
```

Use floats to direct them to where you want them to saty
This should work